# Como agrupar objetos semelhantes

Tags: java, lista

Já bati cabeça e não consegui encontrar uma lógica para fazer isso. Bem, tenho uma lista de objetos (Policie): List e esses objetos tem várias propriedades, como por exemplo: organização, ano, contexto e outros.

O que eu preciso é passar essa lista por um método e ter o resto de uma lista de listas com o agrupamento das políticas que tiverem organização, ano e contexto iguais.

Se por exemplo tenho essas 4 políticas:

```
P1 - organização: USP, ano: 2015, contexto: A
P2 - organização: USP, ano: 2015, contexto: A
P3 - organização: UFCG, ano: 2014, contexto: B
P4 - organização: UFCG, ano:2014, contexto B
```

Os objetos P1 e P2 e os objetos P3 e P4 são semelhantes, o retorno deveria ser duas listas, uma com P1 e P2 e outra com P3 e P4. Alguém poderia me ajudar com a lógica? Obrigado!

Comment: Duas perguntas: Por que essas `policies` não estão num `banco de dados`, onde você poderia simplesmente executar uma consulta? E por que você não pode `iterar` pela lista comparando os objetos e criando uma segunda lista com os itens que você procura?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Crie um `Map` para relacionar um objeto com a lista de objetos semelhantes a ele. Então itere sobre sua coleção, verificando se o objeto já está lá e acrescentando na lista, ou se não está criando uma nova lista.

Esse método funciona melhor (i.e. fica mais simples e eficiente) se o critério de similaridade se der por meio do `equals` e `hashCode` dos seus objetos. Se não for o caso, sugiro criar um *wrapper* que opere dessa maneira.

```
Map<Policy, List<Policy>> semelhancas = new HashMap<Policy, List<Policy>>();
for ( Policy p : lista ) {
    List<Policy> semelhantes = semelhancas.get(p);
    if ( semelhantes == null )
        semelhancas.put(p, semelhantes = new ArrayList<Policy>());
    semelhantes.add(p);
}
```

Exemplo usando um *wrapper*:

```
class PolicyWrapper {
    private Policy policy;
    public PolicyWrappr(Policy policy) {
        this.policy = policy;
    }

    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        Policy outra = ((PolicyWrapper)o).policy;
        // Chama o(s) método(s) de Policy que determina(m) se os dois são "similares"
    }

    public int hashCode() {
        // Cria um hash code a partir dos atributos de Policy que caracterizam "semelhança"
    }
}

Map<PolicyWrapper, List<Policy>> semelhancas = ...
for ( Policy p : lista ) {
    List<Policy> semelhantes = semelhancas.get(new PolicyWrapper(p));
    ...
```